# IBM MobileFirst Adobe Air Error

Tags: air, adobe, ibm-mobilefirst

I manage to package adobe air app on MobileFirst platform but am unable to install the .air installation file. I'm prompted with this error: [Installation Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruoYb.png)

I've tried reinstalling Adobe AIR runtime and currently on the latest version.

When I look at my Mac Console, I see the following error. Did I miss anything during packaging?

---

Dec 28 11:54:54 Adobe AIR Application Installer[20848]: Got an unexpected fatal error while unpackaging: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Missing necessary file META-INF/AIR/application.xml" errorID=0]

Dec 28 11:55:01 Adobe AIR Application Installer[20848]: Application Installer end with exit code 7

Dec 28 11:55:01 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruoYb.png) (com.adobe.air.ApplicationInstaller.253928[20848]): Service exited with abnormal code: 7

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention your version number of MobileFirst Platform...

However note that Adobe AIR is a deprecated environment scheduled to be removed in a future release. I would re-consider using it.

From the error you have received you'll need to open a PMR so that it could be investigated by the development team.

Comment: Thanks. I manage to install the .air file on Windows environment. For some reason, it doesn't work on Mac.